# Python - Regarding tkinter and a updating program

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically, I am asking how to put a continuously updating program on display into tkinter's text widget.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Text, BOTH

class FrameApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")

        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Ethis")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.centerWindow()
    def centerWindow(self):
        w = 900
        h = 450
        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (sw - w)/2
        y = (sh - h)/2

        self.parent.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))

    def theText(self):
        w = Text ()
def main():
    root=Tk()
    app = FrameApp(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my tkinter program.  As you can see, I've centered it and set it up with a text function defined as theText(self). I have done anything with theText(self) because I don't know where to begin. This works fine alone, it starts up, as expected, in  the center with it's title.

```
# Money Generator Mark 1
import time

t = 'true'

while t == 'true':
    s = 0
    x = 1
    print ("You have $%s." % (s))
    time.sleep(.75)
    t = 'false'

while t == 'false':         
    s = s + (1 * x)
    print ("You have $%s." % (s))
    time.sleep(.75)
    if s >= 100 and s < 200:
        x = 2 
    if s >= 200:
        x = 4
```

Here I have another program that works fine on it's own. I've dubbed it Money Generator as is akin to Cookie Clicker and Candy Box, those types of things. This also works fine in the command box, function and printing to there.  I was wondering how to integrate these two separate programs so that the second program that is listed here will be displayed in tkinter's window.
Here is my new code that has a new issue.  I'm receiving an error stating that 'generate_money' is not defined in the theText function. These new functions are within my frameApp class.

```
def theText(self):
    self.w = Text()
    self.t = threading.Thread(target=generate_money, args=(self.w))
    self.t.daemon = True

def generate_money(textwidget):
    p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, os.path.join('window.py', 'moneygenerator.py')], 
                         stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in p.stdout:
        do_stuff_with(textwidget, line)
    p.close()
```

Comment: It looks like you've indented that `generate_money` function so that it's part of the `FrameApp` class. Don't do that. That makes `generate_money` into a method of your `FrameApp` objects, instead of a top-level function. (You _could_ make that work, but you'd have to add a `self` parameter to the method, and call it as `self.generate_money` instead of `generate_money`, and there's no good reason to do that here.)

Comment: Also, you're going to have to write a `do_stuff_with` function if you want that to actually do anything besides raise a `NameError` in the background thread.

Comment: Sorry, last question. I've moved generate_money outside of the class. However, I'm still confused about what to put for do_stuff_with. Would I somehow use text.get() to obtain the lines from the thread and then text.insert() to insert them into the text box.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `text.get()`; whatever's in the text widget is already in the text widget, right? Just insert the new lines at the end. (Also, note that the variable is called `textwidget` here, and `self.t` in the class; it's not called `text` anywhere…)

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately going to be a little trickier than you'd like.

The first part is easy: you can just use the `subprocess` module to run the background script and capture its output:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, os.path.join(scriptpath, 'moneygenerator.py')], 
                     stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.stdout:
    do_stuff_with(line)
p.close()
```

The problem is that doing this in the middle of a Tkinter callback will block the entire program until the background program is done. So, instead of getting updated on each line, you'll just freeze up the app until the OS kills you/displays a beachball/etc.

There are two usual solutions to doing stuff without blocking: Do it on a thread—which is easy, except that you can't access Tkinter widgets from a background thread. Or check the subprocess's pipe in a non-blocking way—which would be great if there were a cross-platform way to do that without potentially blocking forever. (There are, however, third-party "async subprocess" wrappers on PyPI, which may be an alternate way to solve this problem.)

So, you need to combine *both* of these. Have a thread that blocks on the subprocess and posts messages on something that you *can* check in a non-blocking way in the main thread, like a `queue.Queue`.

But, instead of writing it yourself, there's a nice wrapper called [`mtTkinter`](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/mtTkinter) that does most of the hard part for you. You can just write your background thread as if it were legal to access the widgets, and it will intercept that access and turn it into queue posts. Sadly, `mtTkinter` doesn't work in Python 3—but it looks pretty easy to fix; I [slapped together a port](https://github.com/abarnert/mttkinter) in a few minutes. Although I haven't done much testing on it, I think this is probably the simplest way forward.

So:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Text, BOTH
import subprocess
import sys
import threading

# ...

def generate_money(textwidget):
    p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, os.path.join(scriptpath, 'moneygenerator.py')], 
                         stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in p.stdout:
        do_stuff_with(textwidget, line)
    p.close()

# ...

class FrameApp(Frame):
    # ...
    def theText(self):
        self.w = Text()
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=generate_money, args=(self.w,))
```

You'll probably want to add some way to either tell `self.t` to shut down early, or just wait for it to finish, at quit time. (Or, alternatively, because you know that it can't leave any "dangerous garbage" behind it killed suddenly, you may be able to just set `self.t.daemon = True`.) But this is enough to show the basics.

Comment: Thanks a ton for replying. I've encountered a problem though. I'm having issues posting the new code here, so I'll update the thread.